# Git change parent of parent commit

Tags: git

I have the following commit tree:

```
master ---A-------D
           \     /
feature1    B---C
                 \
feature2          F---E---HEAD
```

D is a merge commit. So diff between C and F is the same as between D and F.
I want to change parent of F from C to D. I.e. make it look like this:

```
master ---A-------D
           \     / \
feature1    B---C   \
                     \
feature2              F---E---HEAD
```

I've tried `git rebase --onto D C`, it says `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature2` but nothing changes in the commit tree.

Comment: Assuming you're interpreting correctly, and your rebase onto didn't work, one possible explanation could be that you have some merge commits in there.  Rebasing over a merge commit can be tricky, because often you will have to redo the merge.

Comment: This could be added as a challenge in [LearnGitBranching](https://learngitbranching.js.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is:

```
git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
```

Comment: Assuming the drawing is correct (and that we start with `git checkout feature2`), this should do the same as `git rebase --onto D C` since `master` names commit `D` and `feature1` names commit `C`. Note, though, that your version using the names is far easier to get right. :-) I dislike use of a final branch name (in this case `feature2`) in `git rebase` because it has the weird side effect of starting with a `git switch` to that branch and then *leaves you on that branch*, which doesn't "feel right" somehow to me.

Comment: I am not following your _but_. You mean that you don't like it if you are standing on something other than `feature2` because you would end up in `feature2` and not where you started from? I understand but that's not a real problem because if you are on branch X and you want to do this rebase that we are talking about with the rebase without the second branch, you would have to _first_ checkout `feature2` so after the rebase you would end up in exactly the same situation/spot, right?

Comment: That's not really a "but". It's me saying I always do this as `git checkout feature2; git rebase --onto master feature1` in a case like this. That's because I don't like having `git checkout` built into `git rebase`. If `git rebase` went back to the *current* branch on finishing the rebase, then it would make some sense (but now I would dislike it for being overly complicated, like the autostash feature :-) ).